# Application using Gecko Web Browser does not work in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, gecko

I develop a simple C# application using Gecko Web browser component to display a web page into form. In Windows it works perfect, but when I want to run it in Linux running with Mono these errors appear:

[image]

I am using Geckofx60(32 bits) version 60.0.55 downloaded from Nuget. The code is very simple

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
  static class Program
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
      //System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
      System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
      Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox");
      Application.EnableVisualStyles();
      Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
      Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you use Gecko instead of WebView2?  I'm wondering as Microsoft is definitely pushing towards using WebView2 and I assume the support would be better somehow

Comment: You can't run a Windows Forms App on Linux.

Comment: Please let go of Mono https://halfblood.pro/the-end-of-mono/ You also have to choose another framework to build GUI apps on Linux, https://halfblood.pro/the-story-about-net-cross-platform-ui-frameworks-dd4a9433d0ea

Comment: Thanks @Julien. Webview2 doesn't run on Linux or at least I couldn't find the runtime of it.

Comment: Thanks @LexLi, I'll read those articles.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-supported-operating-systems#linux